# Doubt about Entropy of solar radiation on Earth

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, thermal-radiation

This paper $[1]$ gives the following statement:

> On Earth, the low-entropy energy is provided by solar radiation and the high-entropy energy is disposed as infrared radiation emitted into the cold space.

So, what suppose to mean "low-entropy energy"?

$$ * * * $$

$[1]$ https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a black body radiation, entropy of a photon gas is proportional to the cube of its temperature (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas)), which is itself an increasing function of frequency (or decreasing function of wavelength), so indeed, visible light has more entropy than infrared.